# How can I change this frequency checking code to be case-insensitive?

Tags: python, dictionary

sorry if it is a stupid question, but I am new to programming and python. I have such code:

```
dic = {}

for word in text:
    if word in dict:
        dict[word] += 1
    else:
        dict[word] = 1
counter = 0        
for key in sorted(dict, key = lambda x: dict[x]):
    counter += 1
    print(counter, key, dict[key])
```

I want this code to give me the frequency of the word tokens in the text in ascending order and it works. However, it is case-sensitive. I would like it to be case-insensitive. I was trying to use .lower() and unfortunately, it does not work. Can anyone help me, or suggest any solutions? Thank you for any suggestions,

Comment: using lower/upper should have worked... let me write it in an answer

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
from collections import defaultdict
counter = defaultdict(0)
for word in text8:
    word = word.lower()
    counter[word] += 1
```

Ideally, you should use a `Counter`  which does something similar but more efficiently.

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(word.lower() for word in text8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this:

```
text8 = "sadadsad"
countdict = {}
for word in text8:
    countdict[word] = text8.count(word)
print(countdict)
```

This will give you char as a key and value as count of char in text8

Answer (score 0):

[`collection.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is very common class for **BOW**(bag of words).
Plus, you can use `str.lower` method for ignoring cases.
But note that you will lose original case by this way.

```py
from collections import Counter

text8 = [
    'ABC', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'de', 'fg', 'fg'
]

count = Counter(word.lower() for word in text8)
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(count.items()):
    print(i + 1, k, v)
```

output:

```
1 abc 3
2 def 1
3 de 1
4 fg 2
```